# Gtx 770 crashing when opening games

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

My gtx 770 has started crashing when I open games and my windows taskbar has small pixels that disappear after a few seconds and this repeats all the time.

Minecraft and league of legends are worst; they give me huge texture bugs and random colored lines all over the screen.

Battlefield 4 sometimes gives me a directx error message when started and sometimes it crashes without the error message.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, it sounds like the graphics card has developed a fault. Including the specs of your computer (make/model of motherboard, power supply, etc), might be useful.

Have you installed anything new recently that might be causing it?

There are a few things you can try to either see if it can be fixed or to confirm that it's faulty:

- Try the card out in a different computer -- if it continues to crash in another machine it's extremely likely that the card is faulty. I would do this first if you have another machine available (or can use a friend's)
- Update the drivers (unlikely to help, but worth a try)
- Re-seat the card
- Try the card in a different PCIe slot (if your motherboard has any).

Comment: I7 4470k
gtx 770
16gb ram
Sabertooth z87

i tried changing the pci slot but for no use.. any suggestions ?

Comment: If you can't get another machine to try it out in, can you get access to another nVidia card to try in your machine?

Comment: Can't atm is there any way i can have ur skype so i can send u images of the windows thing?

Comment: Oh lordy no, I don't use skype. Add your images to imgur.com (or some other image hosting site) and edit your question to include the links. You also may do better with asking the question on a forum that encourages troubleshooting...SuperUser (and StackExchange sites in general) do not encourage long drawn out conversations...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, that looks like some issue with driver. Try
 uninstalling the Nvidia driver and by uninstall, I mean remove all Nvidia components. Reboot if required.
Then install the driver using Custom Installation, Make sure to check perform clean installation.
That should do it.
Also get latest WhQl driver from web. Do not go for beta.

Comment: Can you explain how this answer is related to the question?

Comment: There are instances where improper installation of driver components (in case you over install a driver over another) leads to performance.issues. also as you have corruption when rendering games points it to the graphics device rendering it. In your case, this has to be the GPU/gpu driver. A clean install ensures that all components are uninstalled and then reinstalled. So there's a solid chance it should be fixed

Comment: Still not sure how this answers the question though